# Newcommand: underbrace parentheses

Tags: macros

I need a newcommand like

\underbrace{}_{},

but I want a parenthese like that ( instead of {.

Comment: Can you provide [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that uses the normal `\underbrace`?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) question: [Adding slurs to words in a text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25612)

Comment: Specifically the `\undergroup` macro from the `mathabx` package.

Comment: \undergroup   can be used in  math mode?  actually the package give me some errors

Comment: package not found

Comment: @AndreaLeo Yes, the `\undergroup` command is a math command. The package is part of TeXLive and MikTeX so it should be either already present in your distribution or easily installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont know it yet, you also might consider using the `\underbracket` command from `mathtools`,  which looks nice and may be customised (height and thickness). Of course there's also an `\overbracket` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\providecommand\given{}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}(){}{
 \renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
 #1}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Var[1]{V}(){}{
 \renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
 #1}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
V(\varepsilon)&=\overbracket[0.4pt]{ E_{X}(\Var{\varepsilon \given X})}^\text{expected value}+V_{X}(\smash[b]{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\EV{\varepsilon \given X}}_\text{$=0$}})\notag
\\ & =E_{X}(\Var{\varepsilon \given X})\notag \\
&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y\vert X})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's the variant of `\underbrace` without the piece in the middle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\underparen[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \vtop{
      \m@th
      \ialign{%
        ##\crcr
        $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
        \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
        \upparenfill\crcr
      }%
    }%
  }\limits
}
\newcommand\upparenfill{%
  $\m@th\setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\underparen{abcdef}_{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small misalignment is only apparent, due to pixel rounding at low resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Here I do it with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine,graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\underparen[1]{\@ifnextchar_{\uphelp{\uparen{#1}}}{\uparen{#1}}}
\makeatother
\def\uphelp#1_#2{\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[1pt]{#1}{\scriptstyle #2}}}
\newcommand\uparen[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackunder[0pt]{#1}{\rotatebox{90}{$\left(%
  \rule[\dimexpr-.5\wd0+\dp\strutbox-1.3pt]{0pt}{\wd0}\right.$}}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}_{a}\quad
\underparen{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\quad
\underparen{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}_{a}\quad
\]
\[
\underbrace{abcde}_{a}\quad
\underparen{abcde}\quad
\underparen{abcde}_{a}\quad
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `abraces` package ("a" for "asymmetric" or "arbitrary") will do this, and a lot more besides. The optional argument specifies the "design" of the brace. See the package documentation for more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}
\begin{document}
$\aunderbrace[l1r]{abcdef}_{x}$
\end{document}
```