# Underbrace or overbrace, in text mode, for a partial word

Tags: brackets, underbrace

Is there any possible to underbrace or overbrace only some letter among word and not the whole word

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 $a\underbrace{pp}_{p}el$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this doing what you want? By the way, the option is called `a4paper`, not `A4paper`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260565/newcommand-underbrace-parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the extensible `\upbracefill` has a minimum width, this alternate approach just scales a normal `\{` (rotated 90 degrees) to the right size (with width limiting).  Thus, to use this approach for a very wide argument, there is an optional argument that can be specified, for example as `[\Bigg]`.

EDITED for `\Toverbrace`, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine, scalerel}
\newcommand\Tunderbrace[3][]{%
  \def\tmp{#2}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\tmp}%
  \stackunder[1pt]{%
    \stackunder[0pt]{\tmp}{\rotatebox{90}{\scaleto[2ex]{#1\{}{\wd0}}}%
  }{%
    \scriptsize #3%
  }%
}
\newcommand\Toverbrace[3][]{%
  \def\tmp{#2}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\tmp}%
  \stackon[1pt]{%
    \stackon[0pt]{\tmp}{\rotatebox{90}{\scaleto[2ex]{#1\}}{\wd0}}}%
  }{%
    \scriptsize #3%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
a\Tunderbrace{pp}{p}le

a\Tunderbrace[\big]{pppppp}{p}le

a\Tunderbrace[\Bigg]{pppppppppppppppp}{p}le

a\Toverbrace{pp}{p}le

a\Toverbrace[\big]{pppppp}{p}le

a\Toverbrace[\Bigg]{pppppppppppppppp}{p}le
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Educ I made an edit that I hope reflects your underlying intent.