# Manually specify width of underbracetext?

Tags: tables, math-mode, underbrace

I would like to increase the width of an `\underbracetext` command. Currently I have:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.15in}{-0in}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
\textbf{Lamotrigine} & \textbf{250mg}       & \textbf{in} & \textbf{the}        & \textbf{morning}     & \textbf{,}     & \textbf{200mg}      & \textbf{at}        & \textbf{night} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\underbracetext{\textbf{Drug}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\underbracetext{\textbf{Direction 1}}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\underbracetext{\textbf{Direction 2}}}
 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

that produces:

[image]

But I would like to increase the length of the second and third braces so that the second one spans from 250 to morning, and the third spans 200mg to night.

i.e. when I say spans from, I mean start the underbrace where the word starts, not from the middle.

Comment: My LaTeX does not have an `\underbracetext` macro, nor could I find a package that contains it, so I dare to assume that it is a user-defined command. Could you post **full** and **compilable** example that produces the output from the picture, please, so that we can help you.

Comment: BTW: you might want to have a look at the `siunitx` package, there are rules as to how units (`250mg`) should be formatted)

Comment: Is this the entire table? If so you may want to try a different approach to this altogether. What exactly do you want to do? Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401971/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128064/35864 can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to put it like this in the table? If not, you may just do

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\[
\underbrace{\textbf{Lamotrigine}}_{\displaystyle\text{\textbf{Drug}}}~
\underbrace{\text{\textbf{250mg in the morning}}}_{\displaystyle\textbf{\textbf{Direction
1}}},~\underbrace{\text{\textbf{200mg at night}}}_{\displaystyle\textbf{Direction 2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several other possibilities, e.g. Ti*k*Z.

Comment: fantastic - what environment does `\[` invoke by the way?

Comment: @brucezepplin `amsmath` redefines it to `equation*`