# Slur over multiple columns in a table

Tags: tables, music

How do I extend the slur to extend over entries in multiple columns in tabular environment i.e. I want to do &\slur{P &M &G} with 3 columns having entries P, M and G and the slur extending over them? Neither Juan's or Steve's solution work as I get an error compiling.
Juan and Steve had proposed two solutions that work well in a text environment but do not span across multiple columns. Here is the link to the original question:
[How do I add slurs (as in music notation) to top of the words in a text? [added follow-up]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611110/how-do-i-add-slurs-as-in-music-notation-to-top-of-the-words-in-a-text-added)

Comment: Not sure what "slur" means, but check out \multicolumn.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.